# Display directory tree output like tree command

Tags: perl, tree, directory, traversal, tree-traversal

I still play with great [`Path::Class`](https://metacpan.org/module/Path%3a%3aClass) module in order to traversing directories. I wrote a piece of code, but I'm not pleased with the displaying of the output. My directory tree output is not as clean-cut and elegant as the output of the `tree` command. :-(

My code so far:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Path::Class;

my $dir = Path::Class::Dir->new('D:\dev\pl\testdir');

my $max_depth = $dir->traverse(sub {
  my ($child, $cont, $depth) = @_;
  return max($cont->($depth + 1), $depth);
}, 0);
sub max { my $max = 0; for (@_) { $max = $_ if $_ > $max } $max };

# Print header
printf "%-43s|%s\n", " Name", " mtime";
printf "%-43s|%s\n", '-' x 43, '-' x 11;

$dir->traverse(sub {
  my ($child, $cont, $indent) = @_;
  my $child_basename = $child->basename;
  my $child_stat     = $child->stat();
  my $child_mtime    = $child_stat->[9];
  $indent //= 0;
  my $width = 40 - 3 * ($indent - 1);

  #print "DEBUG: Scanning $child\n";

  if ($indent == 0) {
    print "ROOT: ", $child, "\n";
  }
  else {
    if ($child->is_dir) {
        print '   ' x ($indent - 1), '+- ';
        printf "%-${width}s| %d", $child_basename . '/', $child_mtime;
        print "\n";
    } else {
        print '   ' x ($indent - 1), '|- ';
        printf "%-${width}s| %d", $child_basename, $child_mtime;
        print "\n";
    }
  }

  $cont->($indent + 1);
});
```

And the my **wrong** output is:

```
Name                                       | mtime
-------------------------------------------|-----------
ROOT: D:\dev\pl\testdir
+- Path-Class-0.25/                        | 1337013211
   |- Build.PL                             | 1329360988
   |- Changes                              | 1329360988
   |- dist.ini                             | 1329360988
   |- INSTALL                              | 1329360988
   +- lib/                                 | 1337013211
      +- Path/                             | 1337013211
         +- Class/                         | 1337013211
            |- Dir.pm                      | 1329360988
            |- Entity.pm                   | 1329360988
            |- File.pm                     | 1329360988
         |- Class.pm                       | 1329360988
   |- LICENSE                              | 1329360988
   |- Makefile.PL                          | 1329360988
   |- MANIFEST                             | 1329360988
   |- META.yml                             | 1329360988
   |- README                               | 1329360988
   |- SIGNATURE                            | 1329360988
   +- t/                                   | 1337013211
      |- 01-basic.t                        | 1329360988
      |- 02-foreign.t                      | 1329360988
      |- 03-filesystem.t                   | 1329360988
      |- 04-subclass.t                     | 1329360988
      |- 05-traverse.t                     | 1329360988
      |- author-critic.t                   | 1329360988
```

The **correct** output (and also better looking) should be:

```
Name                                       | mtime
-------------------------------------------|-----------
ROOT: D:\dev\pl\testdir
+- Path-Class-0.25/                        | 1337013211
   |- Build.PL                             | 1329360988
   |- Changes                              | 1329360988
   |- dist.ini                             | 1329360988
   |- INSTALL                              | 1329360988
   +- lib/                                 | 1337013211
   |  +- Path/                             | 1337013211
   |     +- Class/                         | 1337013211
   |     |  |- Dir.pm                      | 1329360988
   |     |  |- Entity.pm                   | 1329360988
   |     |  |- File.pm                     | 1329360988
   |     \- Class.pm                       | 1329360988
   |- LICENSE                              | 1329360988
   |- Makefile.PL                          | 1329360988
   |- MANIFEST                             | 1329360988
   |- META.yml                             | 1329360988
   |- README                               | 1329360988
   |- SIGNATURE                            | 1329360988
   \- t/                                   | 1337013211
      |- 01-basic.t                        | 1329360988
      |- 02-foreign.t                      | 1329360988
      |- 03-filesystem.t                   | 1329360988
      |- 04-subclass.t                     | 1329360988
      |- 05-traverse.t                     | 1329360988
      \- author-critic.t                   | 1329360988
```

**Could you please to improve or correct my code?**

Thanks very much in advance for your help!

Regards,
Scottie

Comment: If the only difference is that the last child of each directory should have a slash instead of a vertical bar leading into it (incidentally you could have said that in the question), I think you're going to have to save up each child's information until all children are processed, then print them out.

Comment: Oh, I see that you've also got a difference with multiple `|` not showing up on those lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My code below is not fancy solution, but it works at you wish >>

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Path::Class;

my $dir = Path::Class::Dir->new('D:\dev\pl\testdir');

my $max_depth = $dir->traverse(sub {
  my ($child, $cont, $depth) = @_;
  return max($cont->($depth + 1), $depth);
}, 0);

sub max { my $max = 0; for (@_) { $max = $_ if $_ > $max } $max };

my @output = ( sprintf("%-43s|%s", " Name", " mtime"),
               sprintf("%-43s|%s", '-' x 43, '-' x 11) );

my @tree = (0, 0);
my $last_indent = 0;

$dir->traverse( sub {
  my ($child, $cont, $indent) = @_;
  my $child_basename = $child->basename;
  my $child_stat     = $child->stat();
  my $child_mtime    = $child_stat->[9];

  $indent = 1 if (!defined $indent);
  my $width = 40 - 3 * ($indent - 1);

  if ($last_indent != $indent) {
    if ($last_indent > ($indent + 1)) {
      for my $level (($indent + 1)..($last_indent - 1)) {
        $output[$#output - $_] = 
          substr($output[$#output - $_], 0, 3 * ($level - 1)) . ' ' .
          substr($output[$#output - $_], 3 * ($level - 1) + 1, 65535) 
            for (0..$tree[$level] - 1);
      }
      delete $tree[$_] for $indent..$last_indent;
    }
    $tree[$indent] = 0;
    $last_indent = $indent;
  }

  if ($child->is_dir) {
    push @output, sprintf("%s+- %-${width}s| %d",
      ('|  ' x ($indent - 1)), $child_basename . '/', $child_mtime);
    $tree[$indent] = 0;
  }
  else {
    push @output, sprintf("%s%s- %-${width}s| %d", ('|  ' x ($indent - 1)),
      ($child eq ($child->dir->children)[-1] ? '\\' : '|' ),
      $child_basename, $child_mtime);
    $tree[$indent]++;
  }
  $tree[$_]++ for (1..$indent - 1);

  $cont->($indent + 1);
});

for my $level (1..$last_indent - 1) {
  $output[$#output - $_] = 
    substr($output[$#output - $_], 0, 3 * ($level - 1)) . ' ' .
    substr($output[$#output - $_], 3 * ($level - 1) + 1, 65535)
      for (0..$tree[$level] - 1);
}

print "$_\n" for @output;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($child->is_dir) {
    printf "%s+- %-${width}s| %d\n",
        ('|  ' x ($indent - 1)),
        $child_basename . '/',
        $child_mtime;
} else {
    printf "%s%s- %-${width}s| %d\n",
        ('|  ' x ($indent - 1)),
        ($child eq ($child->dir->children)[-1] ? '\\' : '|' ),
        $child_basename,
        $child_mtime;
}
```

Also, ASCII lines cause eye cancer. Use the proper [box drawing characters](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/box_drawing/images.htm) instead.

Comment: Thanks! It works better but not ideal - some lines are unnecessary.

Comment: I don't have the patience to program that change, I quit soon for today. I'll give you the hint what to modify: for the first `%s` expression, look up the tree with `parent` $indent times, then call `children` in scalar context. If that directory has more than one child, output a `'|  '` segment, if only one child, output a `'   '` segment.